# Pipe into raw_input() in Python

Tags: python, raw-input, piping

How could I have a program execute a target program, and then enter text into its stdin (such as raw_input.)

For example, a target program like this one:

```
text = raw_input("What is the text?")
if text == "a":
    print "Correct"
else:
    print "Not correct text"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what kind of answer are you expecting?

Yes you can. But you will also put things on stdout that wouldn't be necessary if it is used in a pipe. Furthermore, you'll have to loop over `raw_input` the same way you would loop over `sys.stdin` to get input line by line:

```
while True:
    text = raw_input("What is the text?")
    if text == "a":
        print "Correct"
    elif text == "stop":
        print "Bye"
        break
    else:
        print "Not correct text"
```

But as stated in the [Zen of Python – PEP20](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), *"There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."* and in your case, that would be to use `sys.stdin`.

(Edit): as I may not have understood correctly what the OP is asking, to run another program from within a python program, you need to use [`subprocess.Popen()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)

```
import subprocess

text = "This is the text"

data = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'other_script.py'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate(input=text)
print data[0]
```

Comment: I think what the OP is talking about is having another program run the the original program with access to its raw_input.